# Postman not sending json property

Tags: json, postman

The json body was used before to send a request successuly.
After adding a new property it keep working but the new property is not being sent.
Looking at the history the json body is sent without the new property.

Answer (score -1):

This link helped me: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4925
You can format your json body using **Ctrl+B** and it will be send correctly.